# Single Must Use Plugins Directory for local development

Tags: plugins, wp-config

I have multiple local installations of WordPress and want to have a single Must Use Plugins directory for all my local sites.

Is there anything I can add to wp-config for instance that will let me have a single folder which can be used for all my sites? Or perhaps another approach?

For instance:

/root/sites/site1/...
/root/sites/site2/...
/root/sites/site3/...

all use:

/root/mu-plugins/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` constant in the config file of each of the sites (and `WPMU_PLUGIN_URL` for the url).

By default it is defined as:

```
WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/mu-plugins'
```

Comment: Thanks and here is the specific code I used: // set global mu-plugins directory
define( 'WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/WP-Globals/mu-plugins' );

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a symbolic link within wp-content for each site:

```
ln -s /root/mu-plugins mu-plugins
```